# Kafka messaging and GUI data exchange in java

Tags: java, swing, apache-kafka, concurrency

I have an application that is required to use Kafka as the messaging system. I also have a GUI that takes user inputs. The application is set up to kick off heavy crunching when receiving a message from the topic.  The majority of the data comes from the message, but I need to grab info in the form of user entered information to set default values. I have to use Java 8 and this is a Java core application. I have a Java Swing UI that I inherited and am not looking to build a new UI from scratch. I would also like to display the results of the heavy crunching in GUI upon completion.

I am using the Kafka streams API to grab the message,  flatMapValue to kick of the crunching and return the results to another topic.

How do I get info from text fields to pass to my crunching piece?  How do I return the results to the GUI to be displayed?

Comment: This is a vast question, however I think your Swing application (or its backend if they're separated) should be a Kafka producer. Your GUI should accept eventual dependency (displaying some message or something that the data is possibly not up to date) and probably get its data from a database that is filled by Kafka itself once the processing is over.

Comment: The GUI is more of an engineering display. One topic has the bulk of the Information needed to do the calculations,  the second topic is where the response is posted (why I am using Streams).

Comment: It would be useful if you showed your code, but it's unclear what issues you're having creating a ProducerRecord from your input fields or having a consumer populate data in the GUI

Comment: Sorry I can't share my code.  If I create the GUI in one thread and have kafka streams in another thread, how do I pass data from the GUI thread to the kafka thread? I have started the gui thread with invokeLater.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. It was much simpler than I tried to make it.  I was able to pass data from the GUI with action Listeners and get stuff in the GUI using static variables and invokeLater.